# How to include static data files into luarock?

Tags: lua, luarocks

This is my first time creating a luarock and writing `.rockpec` file. I have a small lua script and some static text files that this script requires to use. How should I *pack* my luarock so that these static files are available for my script?

For example, here is my `myscript.rockspeck` file:

```
package = "myscript"
version = "1.0-1"
source = {
   url = "https://github.com/me/myscript/raw/master/myscript-1.0.tar.gz",
   tag = "v1.0"
}
description = {
   summary = "My script.",
   detailed = [[
      Some lua script.

   ]],
   homepage = "https://github.com/me/myscript",
   license = "MIT"
}
dependencies = {
   "lua >= 5.1, < 5.4"
}
build = {
   type = "builtin",
   modules = {
       myfun = "src/myscript.lua"
   },   
   copy_directories = {"my_data"}
}
```

I am able to do :

```
luarocks pack myscript-1.0-1.rockspec
sudo luarocks install myscript-1.0-1.src.rock
```

However, upon importing `myfun` module I can see that the `my_data` directory with the required files inside is not accessible by the module as it complains accordingly.

When I do `laurocks pack` my working directory contains `myscript-1.0.tar.gz` with the following sctructure:

```
myscript-1.0/
    src/myscript.lua
    tiny_data/
        data1.txt
        data2.txt
```

How should I correctly include `my_data` static files?

Comment: Checkout this project https://github.com/hishamhm/datafile